# Why does Scala complain of type mismatch?

Tags: scala, future

I have a method like:

```
  private def _createConfig(
      app:            String,
): Future[Config] = {
    secret.map { secret =>
      Config(
        action        = s"SP_$app",
        clientSecret     = secret, 
      )
    }
  }
```

and another method which consumes this:

```
  private def setup(
      app:                String,
      someCondition:      Boolean = false
  ): EitherT[Future, Throwable, String] = {
    Given("I create a partner")
    for {
      something <- createSomething()
      _ = if (someCondition) And(s"I do some action") else Done
      _ <- if (someCondition) createAnotherSomething(something) else doneEitherT

      _ = Then(s"I create a configuration for partner $partner and app $app")
      _ <- _createConfig(app)
      
    } yield something
  }
```

`doneEitherT` is defined as:

```
final lazy val doneEitherT = Future.successful(Done.upcast).rightT[Throwable]
```

When I build this the compiler complains that there's a type mismatch:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[String]
 required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Throwable,String]
      _ <- _createConfig(app)
```

Why does the compiler expect `_createConfig(app)` to be of type `EitherT`? Are all methods inside a `for` block supposed to match the signature of the method? New to scala and working with Futures :/

Comment: As a rule of thumb, every right-hand side of `<-` in a for-comprehension has to be of same  type, so `EitherT[Future, Throwable, A]` in your case.

Comment: Can you post a link for this? i.e. Documentation - I want to understand this better

Comment: It's a rule of thumb. Look into how for comprehensions are desugared if you want to get better understanding, then look at how `flatMap` is defined on `EitherT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comments section, types in for comprehension should be aligned and the compiler complains about that: you invoke `flatMap` on `EitherT` (implicitly via `<-`) and as a result return `Future` instead of expected `EitherT`.

You need to change return type and re-implement next method:

```
private def _createConfig(app: String): EitherT[Future, Config, Throwable] = EitherT {
    secret.map { secret =>
      Right(Config(action = s"SP_$app", clientSecret = secret)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Or just use `EitherT.right[Throwable](_createConfig(app))` in the for-comprehension, if you need the plain future version somewhere else or don't like transformers in signatures.

Comment: That explains a lot! I used `EitherT.right[Throwable](_createConfig(app))` instead (this worked). Many thanks!